# React Native - Is there any way to import Google reviews (or any sort of reviews) into my book app

Tags: react-native

hope everyone is doing well. I just got done with a udemy course on react native and am in the process of making my first practice app. It is a book app. I wanted to add a section where users can read reviews about the book from other people. I want to have a rating system and the whole lot. I just wanted to know if there's any way to import those Google book reviews (rating and comments) into my react native app? It could be reviews from any genuine website but I just wanted to know if I can import anything at all. Searching this on Google just points me to the google in app review api which is not at all what I'm looking for at the moment.

Update 27/12/21: As advised in the comments, I've tried searching for Book APIs. Google Books API doesn't seem to return any public ratings or reviews. Goodreads API doesn't work anymore. I dont think there are any other APIs that return public ratings. I think the New York Times API just returns their own review. That's all. What do you suggesst I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a good website that rates books for example [amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/pricing/) and then [fetch from there API](https://rapidapi.com/blog/how-to-use-an-api-with-react/) what ever you need from what ever they offer .